# selenium. x path for data in carousel

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I expect the script below to print a bunch of car names

I think I'm not pointing to the carousel properly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"../Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.nationwidevehiclecontracts.co.uk/?msclkid=22db17e69fc512c5ab9f49993f841304&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=B%20-%20NVC%20Brand%20-%20(Exact)&utm_term=nationwide%20car%20leasing&utm_content=Brand%20Variations')
carousel_x_path="/section[@class='section section--widget section--full-carousel section__heading-scroll variant-display']"
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,carousel_x_path)));

for name in (driver.find_elements_by_xpath(carousel_x_path+"/span[@class='make']")):
    print("it found a name")
    print(name.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\miniiiiii.py", line 10, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,carousel_x_path)));
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

can you please tell me whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.nationwidevehiclecontracts.co.uk/?msclkid=22db17e69fc512c5ab9f49993f841304&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=B%20-%20NVC%20Brand%20-%20(Exact)&utm_term=nationwide%20car%20leasing&utm_content=Brand%20Variations')
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//body[@name='top']/section[@id='hotdeals']")))
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body[@name='top']/section[@id='hotdeals']/div[@id='offer-carousel']/div[@class='slick-list draggable']//h3//a")
for name in links:
     print name.text
```

**Note:** please add below import to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: hi, that only prints the first 3 that fit. i want all of the slides the carousel might show

Comment: Yes , DOm is refreshing and because of that its listing on 3 elements which is present if you want to show all elements then you have to write separate logic which will avoid to store duplicate valye. hope this will help to you.